# Cannot access JSonSlurper array objects via loop

Tags: groovy, jira, jsonslurper

I am trying to access Jira Rest API using Groovy. (And this question is not Jira-specific.)

There is no problem on connection; I can get the JSON data that I want.

When I tried to iterate over a JSON array in the data; I failed. However, if I tried to access the JSON array's value at specified index; I can get the data.

```
String out_json = get("https://jiraserver.intra/rest/api/2/search/?jql=project%20%3D%20TEST%20ORDER%20BY%20key%20ASC&startAt=0&maxResults=1", authString); // It returns the json data
def out = new JsonSlurper().parseText(out_json)

def key = out.issues[0].key // I can access the key this way

for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
    out.issues[i].key // And it returns null
    break;
}
```

For the one who doesn't know the JSON, it is something like:

```
{
    "total": 2,
    
    "issues": [
        {
            "key": "TEST-1"
            -- some other key-values --
        },
        {
            "key": "TEST-2"
            -- some other key-values --
        }
    ]
}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Your example-json is invalid. Please provide an proper aproximation. Also you would get an NPE if you access `key` on `null` (no existant in list). So most likely you have some misconception of what your data actually is like.  You can e.g. debug with `.keySet()` on your "issue" to find out more about your data.

Comment: Also, shouldn't `issues[i].key` be `out.issues[i].key`?

Comment: I updated the question; both the json and out.issues part.